# Solspace Freeform Pro - How to pull URL title into the email subject

Tags: channel-entries, solspace-freeform

I am using Solspace Pro form on my website and I have no clue on how to change the subject of the email. I will be glad to know if there is a way to pull the title of a detailed page of a listing into the email subject.
When a form on a detailed page is filled, I want to pull the title of that detailed page into the subject of the email when notification is sent.

Answer (score 1):

The Subject is set under the Notifications tab. There you will see a list of your notifications templates. Choose the template you are using for the form in question.

For grabbing the page title, and I'm assuming the form is wrapped in a channel entries tag pair, create a hidden form field  my_subject or something, and assign it a value of {url_title}.

Then in your notification template put {my_subject} in as the value along with whatever you'd like in for the value of the Subject field.